# Node JS Express Retrieve Image from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm able to upload images to my server then to the Postgresql database. I'd like to view an image on the browser by inputting the url like "http://localhost:5000/photoURL/photoURL_1665529814000.jpg" but nothing is displayed. Below is my code

```
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./photoURL", /*(req, file,cb) => {
        cb(null, __dirname+'/images/')
    },*/
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file);
        return cb(null,`${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
    }})
const upload = multer({storage: storage });
router.use('/photoURL',express.static('photoURL'));
router.use(cors());
router.use(express.json());
router.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//add doctor to database
router.post('/',upload.single('photoURL'), (req, res, next)=> {

    //const myid = seconds;
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const contact = req.body.contact;
    const speciality = req.body.speciality;
    const photoURL = `http://localhost:5000/photoURL/${req.file.filename}`;
    
    const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO doctors (username, password, contact, speciality, photourl) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);';
    pool.query(sqlInsert,[ username,password, contact, speciality, photoURL, ], (error, results) =>{
        if (error) { 
            throw error
          }
          
          
          res.status(200).json({
            
            message: "Successful insertion to database",
            
            username: username,
            password: password,
            contact: contact,
            speciality: speciality,
            photoURL: photoURL
            
        })
       // res.send(results.rows);
    console.log(results.rows);
          
    });
    
    
});
```

Comment: destination for multer.diskStorage is a function, not a string. [See Here](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

destination for multer.diskStorage is a function, not a string. So your, storage will look like this

```
import path from 'path'
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, './'))  /* Will store in current directory*/
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file);
        return cb(null,`${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
    }})
```

To access your file, use app.use() middleware in index file

```
app.use(
 '/photoUrl',
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, './yourstoredfilepath'))
);
```